# How to code a test for a method using Date.toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, locale

I have a method using `Date.toLocaleDateString();` in a period:

```
let start = startDay.toLocaleDateString();
let end = endDay.toLocaleDateString();
```

And returning them:

```
return `${weekNumber}: ${start} - ${end}`;
```

In our team we work with several nationalities (thus, locales) and if a test does not pass we cannot commit, now tests are failing depending the locale...

How can I code a test that works correctly?

- There is a way to force system locale?

or maybe...

- Must I code various test for locales, iterate over `navigator.languages` and execute only the default one in machine executing test suites?

Comment: It's a pity that there isn't any answer to this simple question in whole internet. I hate unit testing, and unit testing in javascript in particular.

Answer (score 1):

`jasmine.clock()` will let you [mock the date](https://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date) – you could write cases for each locale you are interested in.